# Store a group of elements form one multimap to another multimap

Tags: c++, std, multimap

let's suppose that I have this multimap

```
std::multimap<char,int> mymm;

mymm.insert (std::make_pair('x',10));
mymm.insert (std::make_pair('y',20));
mymm.insert (std::make_pair('z',30));
mymm.insert (std::make_pair('z',40));
```

Then, I want to find all element that has a specific key "z" in `mymm` to be stored in on another multimap `std::multimap<int,int> mymm2;` So the element inside `mymm2` would be:

```
keys values
z    30
z    40
```

how I can do such a thing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) has all we need:

```
// Retrieve the range of values with key 'z'
auto r = mymm.equal_range('z');

// Construct the new multimap from that range
std::multimap<char,int> mymm2{r.first, r.second};
```

Comment: I have spent a long time searching for that documentation :(. Thanks a lot @quentin.

Comment: @emadalamoudi hold onto it then -- the search function is a bit broken, but the content is extremely useful.